# Elif problems: error parsing expression misplaced elif

Tags: character-encoding, godot

I am having trouble with using elif in godot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsHpi.png)

The code is found in picture format (having trouble copy pasting code onto this text.)

the error that shows up is: Error parsing expression, misplaced: elif

I am trying to follow along coding through this tutorial (https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/getting_started/first_2d_game/03.coding_the_player.html)

I am having trouble coding the player and using elif in the code. Could anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

I have tried looking for spelling error and tinkered with indents.

Nothing happened elif is still as far as I can tell the only point of error in this situation.

Comment: @Bugfish I used the elif because the tutorial said to use it. I will change it to if and see what happens thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using elif after an else. it' s unreachable code.

I am not sure why you need to use elif there at all, because it does not seem to be part of the if else statement above.

So just replace it with a simple if.

Edit:
To be more clear. An if statement can look like this

```
if a:
    #something
else:
   #something
```

or if it has to be a bit more nested:

```
if a:
    #something
elif b==0:
    #something
else:
```

elif can't follow an else, nor be the first part of the statement. It always follows an if

UPDATE:
I did take another look into the tutorial you posted and think I know what the problem is. It seems like you copied every line of code in the tutorial, but you did not follow the indentation.
The elif is part of the if "velocity.x != 0:"
everything in between has to be indented.

Also I think you copied to much code.

```
if velocity.x < 0:
    $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
else:
    $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
```

is just another way to write $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = velocity.x < 0 and $AnimatedSprite.flip_v = velocity.y > 0. So should not be a part of your code again..

the position stuff shouldn't be there also..

If you follow the tutorial 1:1 your code for the process function should look like this:

```
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO # The player's movement vector.
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
    velocity.x += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
    velocity.x -= 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_down"):
    velocity.y += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
    velocity.y -= 1

if velocity.length() > 0:
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
    $AnimatedSprite.play()
else:
    $AnimatedSprite.stop()
position += velocity * delta
position.x = clamp(position.x, 0, screen_size.x)
position.y = clamp(position.y, 0, screen_size.y)
if velocity.x != 0:
    $AnimatedSprite.animation = "walk"
    $AnimatedSprite.flip_v = false
    # See the note below about boolean assignment.
    $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = velocity.x < 0
elif velocity.y != 0:
    $AnimatedSprite.animation = "up"
    $AnimatedSprite.flip_v = velocity.y > 0
```